# Ways to backup AWS Athena views

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

In an AWS Athena instance we have several user-created views. 
Would like to back-up the views. 
Have been experimenting using AWS CLI 
`aws athena start-query-execution --query-string “show views...`
and for each view
`aws athena start-query-execution --query-string “show create views...`
and then 
`aws athena get-query-execution --query-execution-id...`
to get the s3 location for the create view code.

Looking for ways to get the view definitions backed up.
If AWS CLI is the best suggestion, then I will create a Lambda to do the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [SHOW VIEWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/show-views.html) is the best option.

Then you can get the Data Definition Language (DDL) with [SHOW CREATE VIEW](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-view.html).

There are a couple of ways to back the views up.  You could use GIT (AWS offers [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/)).  You could definitely leverage [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/) in a Lambda Function using [Boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codecommit.html).

In fact, just by checking the DDL, you are in fact backing them up to [S3].

Consider the following DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE default.dogs (
  `breed_id` int, 
  `breed_name` string, 
  `category` string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
LOCATION
  's3://stack-exchange/48836509'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

and the following view based on it.

```
CREATE VIEW default.vdogs AS SELECT * FROM default.dogs;
```

When we show the DDL:

```
$ aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "SHOW CREATE VIEW default.vdogs" --result-config
uration OutputLocation=s3://stack-exchange/66620228/
{
    "QueryExecutionId": "ab21599f-d2f3-49ce-89fb-c1327245129e"
}
```

We write to S3 (just like any Athena query).

```
$ cat ab21599f-d2f3-49ce-89fb-c1327245129e.txt
CREATE VIEW default.vdogs AS
SELECT *
FROM
  default.dogs
```

Comment: Thanks.I will make scripts to back the views up. And also scripts to reapply.

Comment: YW.  I love this question.  As someone with a RDMS background, the concepts of testing, version control, and CI/CD issues on database and query systems fascinate me.